# How to better understand Hacker Rank problems

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm trying to level up my skills by doing [Hacker Rank](https://www.hackerrank.com/) challenges, however, some of the problem descriptions aren't clear to me.

For instance, [in this problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/electronics-shop/problem), the function will receive 3 arguments: an integer and 2 arrays. So, why in both example solutions, the input values don't match?

One shows the example input is 3 arrays:

```
10 2 3
3 1
5 2 8
```

and the other shows 1 array and 2 integers:

```
5 1 1
4
5
```

Am I understanding this right?

Comment: Regarding the "how to better understand" question...  Just read all the words, man.  Your question is clearly presented and nicely formatted.  It took some care and effort, and I respect that.  I think you should respect the guy who wrote that Hacker Rank question.  He tried hard to make it clear and easy to understand, but you didn't even give him a chance.  You just read the first bit, and then dismissed all the rest of that work as unimportant.

Answer (score 1):

The input you get is 3 integers (the first line) and two arrays (2nd and 3rd line).
The first number in line one gives you your budget and number two and three give you the length of the two following arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Quote: "The first line contains three space-separated integers b, n, and m, the budget, the number of keyboard models and the number of USB drive models."

The "number of" integers are list/array length. In the second example, the two lists/arrays are of length 1.